# Milter (opendkim): error connecting to filter: Connection refused by localhost

Tags: ubuntu, dkim, opendkim

I'm on Ubuntu 16 LTS, trying to sign mail with `opendkim` and I'm getting:

```
$ tail /var/log/mail.err
...
Milter (opendkim): error connecting to filter: Connection refused by localhost
```

I have `sendmail` configured with:

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`opendkim', `S=inet:8891@localhost')dnl
```

And in `/etc/opendkim.conf` I have:

```
Socket inet:8891@localhost
```

When I check with `lsof` I don't see anything listening on 8891:

```
 $ sudo lsof -i :8891 -n
 [nothing]
```

Looking at `opendkim`'s status it says it's running:

```
 $ systemctl status opendkim.service
 ...
 Active: active (running)
 ...
```

Why isn't it listening on 8891?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another configuration file for opendkim, `/etc/default/opendkim`, and that file specifies a different default socket:

```
# Command-line options specified here will override the contents of
# /etc/opendkim.conf. See opendkim(8) for a complete list of options.
...
SOCKET="local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock"
```

Commenting out that line, and putting in `SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"` below, worked.

Comment: Sockets have less overhead than network connections.

Comment: This was totally it for me. Followed a tutorial... had everything right but missed that there was this previous SOCKET line in the conf file

Answer (score 2):

On my system, I found that I had to change

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/opendkim.service
```

from

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p inet:8891@localhost
```

And then to

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and

```
service opendkim restart
```

after which I could see it listening:

```
netstat -nalp | grep 8891
```

For some reason the opendkim.conf was not used to specify the port.

HTH,

M

Comment: Wow totally intense I had to combine your solution with the accepted answer to get it working. I originally followed this guide: https://philio.me/setting-up-dkim-with-sendmail-on-ubuntu-14-04/